# can not install git-ftp on windows 8

Tags: git, installation, git-bash, git-ftp

Newest git-bash installed, but can not install `git-ftp`.

I follow [git-ftp-for-windows](http://anantgarg.com/2013/09/25/git-ftp-for-windows/):

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp git-ftp.git
cd git-ftp.git && chmod +x git-ftp
cp ~/git-ftp.git/git-ftp /bin/git-ftp
```

But `cp: cannot create regular file ‘/bin/git-ftp’: Permission denied`

Comment: You have to do it with root access. Mainly the `/bin` directory is root or permission specific to have access. 

Try: `sudo cp ~/git-ftp.git/git-ftp /bin/git-ftp`

Comment: @Yoram de Langen windows do not have root or sudo. And my account is administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the answers from [Konstantin Khomoutov](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/1DM57S-EIVs)
Just right click Git Bash, run as administrator,then `cp ~/git-ftp.git/git-ftp /bin/git-ftp` would be fine.